# Modelling A->B or B->A relationship

Tags: regression, modeling, binomial-distribution

I am trying to model the order in which two events (A and B) happen. That is, for a sample I know that,

```
A->B happens 500 times
B->A happens 350 times
```

I tried applying a simple Binomial model,

```
#A->B ~ Bin(theta, #A->B + #B->A)
```

And that model can easily be fit in a Bayesian setting with proper priors. There are some additional covariates in the model that I have omitted for clarity.

Now the challenge is that A and B has some probability of occurring separately. That is, sometimes only B is observed, and sometimes only A is observed. I would like to somehow include these base probabilities, p(A) and p(B), in the model to give an estimate of,

```
1. What is the odds of observing A AND B
2. What is the probability of observing A->B
```

Any advice, pointers to other model/threads or literature is much appreciated!

Cheers.

Edit 1: No good answers on this yet, still hoping for some input.

Comment: Please **do not** edit your question just to make it again visible in the recent questions list.